# rename netcdf global attribute using xarray in python

Tags: python, python-xarray

Is there a way to rename global attribute names using xarray? The `rename` command only seems to rename variables and dimensions and not global attributes.  I tried this:

```
with util.open_or_die('AA.nc', perm='r+') as hndl_nc:
    hndl_nc.rename({'src_name': 'dst_name'}, inplace=True)
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: NetCDF: Attribute not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xarray `attrs` attribute (which holds the attributes you're accessing) is simply an OrderedDict. There's no method in xarray that explicitly allows this behavior, but the `attrs` can be modified directly, e.g.:

```py
hndl_nc.attrs['dst_name'] = hndl_nc.attrs.pop('src_name')
```

Comment: thanks @delgadom! is there a way I can delete an `attrs` as well? e.g. delete `dst_name` instead of renaming it?

Comment: `attrs.pop` removes and returns the value of dst_name. So there shouldn't be any value for `dst_name` after this line. If you just to remove it you could just use the later half of the line.